# Can I make a unique constraint in Oracle on a combination of 2 columns from 2 different tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Column A is the PK of table A. Column B is a column in table B. Column C is a FK is table B that references column A in table A.
[image]

Can I define a constraint that says that that a column B AND column C have to be unique? As in, I don't want any repeats of the same combination of values from A and B.

[image]

Here's one possibility i'm thinking about:

1. Create a unique ID column.

`unique_id varchar2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS (B || '-' || FK that references column A) VIRTUAL`

2. set it as unique

`CONSTRAINT unique_id UNIQUE`

If i go with this solution i'm confused about one thing. The docs say: "Virtual columns are not supported for index-organized, external, object, cluster, or temporary tables." Obviously, because they don't get stored like other columns. Would this be a problem if I wanted to make my tables clustered?

Comment: You need a foreign key constraint.

Comment: C is not a column in a different table. It is a foreign key, yes, but it is still just a column in table B. So you just want a unique constraint on columns  B and C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a `UNIQUE` constraint on two columns. For example:

```
create table table_a (
  a number(6) primary key not null
);

create table table_b (
  b number(6) not null,
  c number(6) not null,
  constraint uq1 unique (b, c),
  constraint fk1 foreign key (c) references table_a (a)
);
```

Then, if you try to insert it will fail for duplicates. For example:

```
insert into table_a (a) values (1);
insert into table_a (a) values (2);
insert into table_b (b, c) values (10, 1);
insert into table_b (b, c) values (10, 1); -- fails!
insert into table_b (b, c) values (10, 2);
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c553064a8c7b122b7367989c3902f5dc).

Comment: One hint, unique constraints does allow null values. So a pair of value B10 - CNull and B10-C1 is possible. You may need then "Not Null" constraint additionally.

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 Thanks for pointing that out. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

The ask was if you could create a unique constraint on two columns for different tables. I'm pretty sure the answer to that question is NO.